# mved a lot of files to the same name - recovery possible

Tags: mv

What exactly happens on file system level (ext4) when you mv one file over another file?

Accidentally mved quite a lot of files over **one** other file. I wonder if it is possible to somehow restore the "lost" files.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as for `rm`ed files. (ie regular deleted files)

Either way the files are now unlinked and recovery if practical will be by the same means.